# How to post UL appended messages to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html-lists, message

I have a site in where appended messages submitted to an Unordered List act as a messenger/chat system. My problem, now my site is active, is that the messages appended dont appear on other users screens. Meaning that what messages you submit, are only local to your screen. What I need is that if a message is submitted, it appears for everyone to see.

Now I'm pretty sure this is because my messages arent powered by PHP, so theyre not being uploaded to the server. Theyre staying local. How do I upload these messages to the server? Is it Javascript? Would anyone be able to get this working?

My HTML is:

```
<ul id="messagebox" ></ul>
<div>
    <input type="text" id="typetextbox" maxlength="100"  autocomplete="off" />
    <button type="submit" id="submit" onblur="submit"> </button>
</div>
```

And my Javascript is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#typetextbox').keypress(function (e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13 ) $('#submit').click();
    });

    $('#submit').click(function(){
        var message = $('#typetextbox').val();
        if (message.replace(/ /g, '')){
            var positions = makeNewPosition();
            var el = $('<li>'+message+'</li>');
            el.attr('gridpos', positions[0].toString()+"x"+positions[1].toString())
            el.css('left', positions[1] * window.li_width);
            el.css('top', positions[0] * window.li_height);
            el.fadeIn(200);
            $('#messagebox').append(el);
        }
    });

});
```

If anyone has ideas to how I get this working it'd be greatly appreciated.

Also if I'm not totally clear, let me know!

Comment: This is only a suggestion, but if you would like to avoid using php, you can build a chat service with only javascript using [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! However, my chat service is already built and working well...apart from the fact its still only local.

Comment: Ah, ok. I would still recommend looking into it, though. It's a real-time data transfer service which deals in JSON. It's great for lightweight apps, and your functions wouldn't need to be changed very much.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a server to manage the state of sent and received messages between each of your clients. I suggest doing some research on WebSockets.

I use http://pusher.com/ as a publish/subscribe event manager so that all known subscribers will receive messages published to a particular channel (aka room or topic).  They provide several examples, including real-time chat demo.

Another option is http://socket.io/ which also has a demo chat application and source code.

It's certainly worth your time to use one of these real-time messaging systems if you're creating a chat application.